# Strange issue with Canvas in Internet Explorer 9, is there any constraint of width and size of canvas/context?

Tags: html, canvas, internet-explorer-9

I have a very simple code which draws a image on a large canvas (2560 * 2560), which works perfectly in FireFox but in IE the images are not getting rendered after a particular width and height (approximately after 2200). Canvas does respond to click events in that area.

Check the code:

Is this a bug with IE9, or a design constraint of width and size of canvas/context?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:#000;width:2560px;height:2560px;">
        <canvas id="map" width="2560px" height="2560px"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script
    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function () {
            for (var y = 0; y < 2560; y += 256) {
                for (var x = 0; x < 2560; x += 256) {
                    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 256, 256);
                }
            }
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
            ctx.fillRect(2400, 2400, 100, 100);
        };
        img.src = "http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@157000000&hl=en&x=9&y=28&z=6&s=Ga";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no size limitation in the spec but MSIE might have chosen to limit the memory used by the canvas to 20 MB (note that each pixel requires 4 bytes).

Comment: Note that `width=` and `height=` require numbers without `px`.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any problem with IE 9.0.8112 on Windows 7.

It may be specific to your computer, too few resources or something.

Is this example below not working for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/5QrVk/6/

For the record, having a smaller canvas and translating it when you want to view more is almost always a good idea. What are you doing that needs such a large space?

Comment: It works for me too (Vista, same IE version). Also adding a click event handler works just fine.

Comment: it seems to be machine specific issue, the jsfiddle.net and even my own code is working on my home box. I will checkback on my work box and will update the thread.

Comment: What I really wants do a show huge floor plans on canvas (more like a map)

Comment: What you really want is a smaller canvas (probably) and to use the concept of a viewport, using context.translate(x,y) to scroll.

Comment: Even the fiddle is not working on my work box - IE Version: 9.0.8112.16421 Update Versions: 9.0.1 (KB2530548), Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: The canvas is getting clipped at 256 * 8, so with above fiddle i am only able to grid of 8 * 8 images.

Comment: @Simon - Can you please point some reference for using translate for a bigger canvas?

Comment: Ajay, I will make a small example of how it is done and notify you when it is complete, but it may take a few days as I am going away soon.

Comment: @Simon - thanks a lot, i tried it. But translate is not helping me to scroll, also the problem of 2048 * 2048 is not getting solved. May be I have not implemented correctly.